# Crystal Reports SP21 - Visual studio 2017 loading very slow

Tags: crystal-reports, report, visual-studio-2017

After installing Crystal reports SP21, Visual Studio 2017 takes several minutes to load a large solution (around 113 projects). If I unistall SP21, the solution loads in a few seconds, as it was before (but Crystal reports won't work). Any ideas about what the problem is or how to diagnose it?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem,
I found this thread

https://answers.sap.com/questions/318334/visual-studio-2017-loading-very-slow.html

Comment: Finally, it's been solved by SAP. Thanks!
https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/2550434